# Find determinant of the matrix NxN

Tags: matrices, determinant

We are given matrix $M_{n,n}$, where
$m_{ij} = \begin{cases} a_i \cdot a_j,\ \mbox{if}\ i \ne j \\a_i^2+k,\ \mbox{if}\ i=j \end{cases}$

Hence, M gotta look like that:
$ \left( \begin{array}_
a_1^2+k & a_1a_2 & ... & a_1a_n  \\
a_2a_1 & a_2^2+k & ... & a_2a_n  \\
... &... &... & ... &\\
a_na_1 & a_na_2 & ... & a_n^2+k \end{array} \right)$

I would like to find the determinant. Any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the difficulty here? I don't think you can find a closed formula for such a general case.

Comment: @7raiden7 I just found this statement, that determinant of triangular matrix is equal to product of diagonal elements. I am going to try Gaussian elimination on that matrix to get at least diagonal values. It doesn't look like easy task because of generality. I will write here when get any progress.

Comment: Yes, but your matrix is not lower/upper triangular. Indeed, it is symmetric, and the determinant is not (unfortunately) just the product of diagonal elements.

Comment: @7raiden7 I guess we have a little misunderstanding. As I stated in my comment earlier, I believe it would be possible to bring this matrix to triangular shape using Gaussian elimination method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace $k$ with $-\lambda$, the determinant you are looking for is the characteristic polynomial of 
$$
(a_i\cdot a_j)_{ij}=B^TB,\ \ \  \text{ where }B=[a_1\ a_2\cdots a_n].
$$
Now note that $BB^T=a_1^2+\cdots +a_n^2$ has rank one, and so $B^TB$ has rank one too. This means that it has one nonzero eigenvalue and then zero with multiplicity $n-1$. The nonzero eigenvalue agrees with that of $BB^T$ (or we can also notice that it has to agree with the trace of $B^TB$).

Thus, the characteristic polynomial of $B^TB$ is $(-\lambda)^{n-1}(a_1^2+\cdots +a_n^2-\lambda) $. We conclude that
$$
\det A=k^{n-1}(a_1^2+\cdots +a_n^2+k).
$$
Note also that this gives us more information, in the sense the eigenvalues of $A$ are precisely $k$ with multiplicy $n-1$ and $k+a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2$ with multiplicity $1$.

Comment: Very clever interpretation!

Comment: I heard of eigenvalues theory, but I am not familiar with it. It would take some time for me to get into it. Thank you for answer, I will upvote+accept or comment on it as soon as I get myself familiarized with theory.

Comment: If you don't know about eigenvalues then this answer is definitely too advanced for you. But it might be a good learning experience to get to understand it.

Comment: Yep. Getting a good learning experience is my main occupation now:)

Comment: Did I take it wrong, or $B^TB$ and $BB^T$ mixed up here? I believe, $B^TB$ couldn't be equal to $a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2$, since $B^T$ has size Nx1, and size of $B$ is 1xN, hence $B^TB$ would result with NxN matrix, isn't? And $BB^T$ should give above-mentioned one-element matrix.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to avoid writing a column vector, but I ended up mixing the transpose. I'll edit in a minute.

Comment: I'm working through solution, but I suppose I am stuck. I will write here my logic: 1. introduce replacement $k = -\lambda$ 2. $det(M) = det(M' - \lambda \cdot I)$ Then, according to definition of the characteristic polynomial, $det(M) = p_{M'}(\lambda)$. (So my M' is a $B^TB$). Then I see understandable part, where we are proving that M' got only one non-zero eigenvalue. But then I don't understand at all this sentence:"The nonzero eigenvalue agrees with that of $BB^T$" and I totally don't understand how we move from $p_{M'}$ to $(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)$.

Comment: Given any two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that both $A_1A_2$ and $A_2A_1$ make sense, then they have the same nonzero eigenvalues (the total number of eigenvalues might be different as $A_1A_2$ and $A_2A_1$ might have different sizes). Simply note that if $ABv=\lambda v$, then $BA(Bv)=\lambda Bv$ (the fact that $\lambda\ne0$ guarantees that $Bv\ne0$).

Comment: Ok. I almost got it figured out. $det(M) = det(B^TB - \lambda I) = p_{B^TB}(\lambda) = p_{BB^T}(\lambda) = (-1)^n(\lambda - (a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)) = (-1)^{n-1}(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2 +k)$
But why do you have $-\lambda$ instead of $-k$?

Comment: You have $k=-\lambda$.

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped. What I ment is that you have $\lambda$ instead of $-1$ under $n-1$, as it supposed to be according to formulae $p_a(\lambda)=(-1)^n \cdot det(A - \lambda I)$